# Recreating this scrolling page effect

Tags: html, css, scroll

This has baffled me completely,i have tried multiple times todo this but i simple cant.I am sure the solution is simple and its something i have looked over.

All help appreciated.

http://techgnotic.deviantart.com/journal/Earth-Day-The-Inspiration-of-the-Natural-World-297767607?utm_source=elnino&utm_medium=messagecenter&utm_campaign=042212_MKT_EarthDay&utm_term=button

Answer (score 2):

Set `background-attachment: fixed` on successive `div`s:

```
div {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 60%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VrQB9/)

You can skip the fixed `height` declaration if your content will determine the height of the `div`. I've included a container `div` to display the effect in the confines of jsFiddle; in practice the `body` will work just fine.